# Set php second configuration ( php.ini file )

Tags: php, configuration

I want to set my own (php2.ini) file, with just a few lines that must overwrite the first php.ini settings - only for those lines.

So I start looking on google and it seems like what I need is the `parse_ini_file` function.

Ok. Now, in index.php I have:

```
parse_ini_file("php2.ini");
phpinfo();
exit();
```

But those settings from php2.ini are not loaded...

Trying to see if the file php2.ini is read-it and it is, beacause if I set `parse_ini_file("php2-not-exist.ini")`, it tells me that the file cannot be found. So the file php2.ini is read, but the settings are not overwritten.

The php2.ini file has inside the next lines:

```
error_log = "errors.log"
display_errors = "0"
max_execution_time = "300"
upload_max_filesize = "60M"
post_max_size = "60M"
date.timezone = "Europe/Bucharest"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding = "UTF-8"
mbstring.http_output = "UTF-8"
mbstring.encoding_translation = "On"
mbstring.func_overload = "6"
```

Trying to let this file with just one line like `post_max_size = "60M"`, but still not overwriting the general php.ini settings.

What am I missing here?

I know that some settings can be setted only and only using the php.ini file configuration. So setting a second file with parse_ini_file witch is a function from php... something is not correct, because some servers doesn't allow you to edit the general php.ini file. So how can the php let you set a second php ini file if you don't have access to the general one ? I don't know if that has something to do with my problem. I'm just saying that maybe here is the problem.

Right now I'm using wamp with php 5.5.12. I just want when I upload my website up, to be all done. I know that some hosting servers lets you to have a second  php.ini file that must be uploaded in public_html or whatever folder it is. This is why I want to set my php2.ini file. To have the website clean when I'll upload to hosting.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to simply place that `php.ini` file in your `public_html`?  This works by default.

Comment: Right now, how I told you, I am am on wamp server, witch has a www folder. So there it is. www folder is like public_html on server. So, should be all good, but is not....

Comment: You mentioned calling your file `php2.ini` and using `parse_ini_file()` which is absolutely not what I said.

Comment: Its work noting that some hosts disable user php.ini, you can check it easily enough just add one in the webroot, if that doesnt work try in the user direcly, its normally the one above webroot. if neither of those work then you can try ini_set in the php files or htaccess but i suspect those would be blocked too.

Comment: I already told you that I am on wamp server, and wamp server settings doesn't have settings like a hosting server. So wamp server is not reading a file like php.ini only if you say him to read it (for example using parse_ini_file). Also note that not all servers accept your php.ini file in public_html. This is why i wanted to set it by myself, if I can, using parse_ini_file. Anyway, Danny Staple gives the answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php parse_ini_file() function reads an ini file into an associative array. It does not set them up as settings like the php.ini file.

There is not a convenience function to override the server settings like this. What you may want here are `.user.ini` (the leading dot is important) files:

> Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for configuration INI files on a per-directory basis.

and:

> In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each directory, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and working its way up to the current document root (as set in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']). In case the PHP file is outside the document root, only its directory is scanned.

For full documentation on that feature, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php.

Note that only a subset of settings can be changed here:

> Only INI settings with the modes PHP_INI_PERDIR and PHP_INI_USER will be recognized in .user.ini-style INI files.

Comment: I understand now, but one more thing. For example display_errors has PHP_INI_ALL and can be setted using an htaccess file. If I can set display_errors using htaccess, why can't I set it using a second php.ini file ? There are all on the server, right ? So user.ini-style must also include PHP_INI_ALL, witch is not.... Anyway... I will use htacces then. I will check each setting if has permission from htacces and this is it. Thank you for your clear answer. I hope I understand you good.